# Vector of pointers to objects c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a base class with 2 derived classes and another one which store objects of the derived classes type:

```
class X
{};

class X1 : public X
{};

class X2 : public X
{};

class Y
{
std::vector<X*> V;
};
```

why doesn't this method of introducing elements in V work?

```
X1 object;
X *ptr = &object;
V.push_back(ptr);
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Note the pointer you put into `V` will be invalid as soon ` object` goes out of scope.

Comment: well this method works, probably something that you didn't show doesn't

Comment: It doesn't work because `V` is a member of the class `Y`. And since this cannot be a member function (because `Y` doesn't have any), and `V` is private, there cannot be an unqualified reference to `V` like this.

Comment: my actual program is more complex. I made this classes to explain the structure of my code. I inserted 2 objects in my vector using 2 methods: first, the one I presented in the question, and it doesn't work because I don't have the object in the vector, and another method which works: V.push_back(new X1(constructor arguments));. I was just curious why my first method doesn't work.

Comment: You are trying to address variable of the class Y without initializing its instance.

Comment: So you're saying this is not your actual code? Then why is it here, in a question about your actual code?

Comment: my code is written in another language so I didn't post it, being afraid that people won't understand it.

Comment: Well, this fake code is useless in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: @user3443903 Make a minimal sample for it that reproduces the behavior you see.

Comment: This code you posted does work with the exception of allocating X1 in a scope instead of creating a new object. Problems with Architecture should be handled with Unit Tests to prevent this kind of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have put your sample code inside a function of class `Y` and can access the class member variable `V`.
The pointer to the locally declared `object` variable is invalid when the function returned. You can fix this by allocating an object from the heap:

```
X *ptr = new X();
V.push_back(ptr);
```

Or even better instead of using raw pointers, use smart pointers if possible, e.g:

```
class Y {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<X> > V;
};

V.push_back(std::make_shared<X>());
```

Comment: Use `std::make_shared<>()` as well.